# How can I get my Tron(TRC20) Address from my Binance Account vie API using Python

Tags: python, api, cryptography, binance

**I wanted to get my Tron(TRC20) Address from my Binance Account vie API using Python, but all i got was my (Eth) Network Address.**

```
**This is my code below.**
rom lib2to3.pygram import Symbols
import os
import config, csv
#and then import it in your python file with
from binance.client import Client
client = Client(config.api_key, config.api_secret)

address = client.get_deposit_address(tag='', coin='USDT')\
USDTron = (address.get('TRC20'))\
```

**Results:**

```
print(address)
Output: {'coin': 'USDT', 'address': '0x1892e6d25a9d91dea9f9caac549261e601af97f8', 'tag': '', 'url': 'https://etherscan.io/address/0x1892e6d25a9d91dea9f9caac549261e601af97f8'}
***(I got my Eth Network Address as the output)***

print(USDTron)
Output: None
**The output was (None)**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you might not quite understand what the python dictionary `get()` method does.

According to [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp) "The get() method returns the value of the item with the specified key."

The output from `client.get_deposit_address(tag='', coin='USDT')` doesnt have a key called TRC20 which is why `get('TRC20')` is returning `None`. If you used `get('url')` it would work and return a value since there is a key called `url` in the dictionary.

Furthermore, in order to retrieve the TRC20 deposit address instead of the default ERC20 address, you need to specify an additional *optional parameter* which is called `network` as defined in the Binance API [docs](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#deposit-address-supporting-network-user_data):

```
address = client.get_deposit_address(tag='', coin='USDT', network='TRX')
USDTron = address.get('address')
```

The network name is found in the dropdown on the binance deposit address webpage. For TRC20 it's TRX.

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works, I wrong by using address = client.get_deposit_address(tag='', coin='USDT', network='TRC20')
USDTron = address.get('address')